# Nested JSON in scala, Circe, Slick

Tags: scala, slick, akka-http, circe

I have a nested JSON in my database. I have figured out the case class for the same. I am using circe, slick and Akka HTTP in my Web api application.

My case class is :

```
case class Sen
  (
    sentences: Array[File]
  )

  case class File
  (
    content: String,
  )
```

I have written GetResult for the same nesting. I have problems with the array in the case class.

```
 implicit lazy val getFile  = GetResult(r => Array[File](r.<<))
 implicit lazy val SenObj = GetResult(r => Sen(getFile(r)))
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Following is the error I get while compiling

```
    Error:diverging implicit expansion for type slick.jdbc.GetResult[T]
starting with method createGetTuple22 in object GetResult
  implicit lazy val getFile  = GetResult(r => Array[File](r.<<))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `getFile` is manually constructing an `Array`, and specifically you're asking for an `Array[File]`. There's no `GetResult[File]`, meaning that `r.<<` won't be able to convert a column value into a `File`.

> Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

You'll at least need a `GetResult[File]` defined.

However, it's not clear from the question how the JSON part is intended to work:

- Perhaps you have a column containing text which your application treats as JSON. If that's the case, I suggest doing JSON array conversion outside of your Slick code layer. That will keep the mapping to and from the database straightforward.
- Or perhaps you have a JSON-type in your database and you're using database-specific operations. In that case, I guess it'll depend on what control you have there, and it probably does make sense to try to do JSON-array operations at the Slick layer. (That's the case for Postgress, for example, via the [pg-slick](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) library)

But that's a different question.

As a general note, I suggest always being explicit about the types of `GetResult` you are defining:

```
implicit lazy val getFile: GetResult[Array[File]]= 
  GetResult(r => Array[File](r.<<))

implicit lazy val SenObj: GetResult[Sen] = 
  GetResult(r => Sen(getFile(r)))
```

...to be clear about what instances you have available. I find that helps in debugging these situations.